# Браузер не отображает код JavaScript c Html

Tags: javascript, html

вот, к примеру, этот код файла html отображается как нужно:

```
<meta charsert='utf-8'>
<script> 
    alert ( 'Привет');
</script>
```

а эти 2 работают и выдают пустую страницу:
1)

```
<meta charsert='utf-8'>
<script> 
    var a = promt('Введите число');
    alert ('Квадрат числа равен ' + a * a);
    var b = promt ('Введите второе число');
    alert('Квадрат второго числа равен ' + b * b);
</script>
```

2)

```
<meta charsert='utf-8'>
<script> 
      var name = promt ('Как вас зовут?');
      alert (name);
</script>
```

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации **смотри консоль**. Консоль, Карл!

Comment: ухxx...) всё заработало!))

Comment: круто. с вас upvote, галка и постоянная мысль в голове, что всегда нужно смотреть ошибки js в консоли!

Comment: charset пишется как `charset`

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что нет никакого *promt*. Есть *prom**p**t*

Comment: Блин, а я не заметил ошибку )